# Cannot implicitly convert type Task<T[]> to Task<IList<T>>

Tags: c#, task

I have multiple async methods that return different sets of `Data`,

```
private async Task<Data> Method1()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    return new Data{Name = "N1"};
}
private async Task<Data> Method2()
{
    await Task.Delay(8000);
    return new Data { Name = "N2" };
}
```

Now I want to run all the above methods in parallel and need to get the result as `list` of `Data`. I am trying this but it's giving error. What is missing here?

```
public Task<IList<Data>> GetAllMethods() =>
        Task.WhenAll(
            Task.Run(() => Method1()),
            Task.Run(() => Method2()));
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Test.Data[]>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IList<Test.Data>>'

Comment: Thanks. tried `Task.WhenAll(
                Task.Run(() => Method1()),
                Task.Run(() => Method2())).Result.ToList();`, but still same error

Comment: Did you read the error message? You can't convert array to list, changing to `Task<Data[]>` may solve it

Comment: Yes, got it. Thanks

Comment: @Pavel Changing the return type to `Task<Data[]>` _will_ solve it. That being said, the current return type is `Task<IList>`, not `Task<List>`. So, _"you can't convert array to list"_ is not relevant here.